# Why I am running into problems with a PHP Date function on IIS?

Tags: php, date, iis, version

I am developing a PHP website but am just trying to test it quickly on some IIS hosting I have (on a sub domain of the original website with is Classic ASP)

The whole page falls down after the third line in the next snippet:

```
$datestring= requestQS("year") . '-' . $monthNumber . '-01 first day of next month';
$dt=date_create($datestring);
$nextMonth = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in

The php version is 5.2.17 so date stuff should work right?

It's working fine on my WAMP install.

Any clues?

Comment: Which problem do you have? Which message is shown? What is the content of `dateString` before trying to convert it?

Comment: $datestring is set on the first line of the 3 I posted. There is no error message, just nothing after the third line will execute

Comment: @I know its there, what I want you to tell me is the content of the variable after you have assigned it. Do an `echo` or a `var_dump` just after it...

Comment: "2013-05-01 first day of next month" Error is now in the question. It doesn't like my "format" line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would say you are trying to convert the $dateString in the wrong way.

Try this:

```
$dateFormat =requestQS("year") . '-' . $monthNumber . '-01';
$dateString = $dateFormat.'first day of next month';

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dateFormat ); 
$nextMonth = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you have to tell PHP to report errors

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   ```

   are the very least
2. You have to [set default time zone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Arh I thought I had errors turned on, apparently not.. I've edited question with error!

Comment: [**Returns a new DateTime instance. Procedural style returns FALSE on failure.**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)